# exponential integral on n-dimensional unit sphere

Tags: integration, exponential-function, spheres

I'd like to compute the expectation of $\exp(\sum x_i)$ under the uniform distribution on the sphere with radius $r> 0$. To this end, I would like to evaluate the following integral:
$$\int_{\large{x_1, \ldots, x_n,\ \sum x_i^2\  =\  r}}\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)\,\mathrm{d}x_1 \ldots \mathrm{d}x_n $$
That is, the exponential of the sum of the (Cartesian) coordinates on the sphere.
Maple cannot do it. It is easy to find results about integrating polynomials on the sphere, and I found something about integrating just $\exp(x_1)$ on the $n$-dimensional sphere, but nothing on the exponential of the full sum.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $x_{i} > 0\ \mbox{or}\ x_{i} \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $x_i \in {\mathbb R}$

Comment: The condition $\displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_{i}^{2} = r$ is not clear ( to me !!! ). For example $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{x_{1}}\left[x_{1}^{2} = r\right]\,\mathrm{d}x_{1}  = \color{red}{\large 0}$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The problem only gets interesting if $n > 1$. Take e.g. $n=2,r=1$, then it is equivalent to integrating $x_1$ from $-1 to $1$ where for each $x_1$, $x_2$ is given by $\sqrt{1-x_1^2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how to integrate $\exp(x_1)$ you know this integral, as follows. Write $e_1$ for the standard basis vector $(1, 0, 0, \dots)$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, where we think of $x = (x_1, \dots x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ as a vector, and write $v = (1, 1, 1, \dots)$ for the all-ones vector. Let me also replace your $r$ with an $r^2$ so that $r$ is the length $\| x \|$, which will make things nicer. You want to compute

$$I(v, r) = \int_{|x| = r} \exp(\langle v, x \rangle) \, dV_x$$

(where $dV_x$ is shorthand I just made up for the volume element $dx_1 \dots dx_n$) and you say you know how to compute

$$I(e_1, r) = \int_{|x| = r} \exp(\langle e_1, x \rangle) \, dV_x.$$

But by spherical symmetry it's clear that $I(v, r)$, as a function of $v$, depends only on the length of $v$! So we can in fact reduce these integrals to each other. Write $v = su$ where $\| u \| = \frac{v}{\| v \|}$ is a unit vector and $s = \| v \|$ is the length of $v$ (which in this case is $\sqrt{n}$). Then

$$\langle v, x \rangle = \langle su, x \rangle = \langle u, sx \rangle$$

and so making the change of coordinates $y = sx$ (so $y_i = sx_i$) we have that

$$I(v, r) = \int_{|y| = sr} \exp(\langle u, y \rangle) \frac{dV_y}{s^n} = \frac{1}{s^n} I(u, sr) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}^n} I(e_1, \sqrt{n} r).$$

Comment: Thanks! Good point, I had overlooked this, simplifies the question a lot. Now about $I(e_1,r)$. The reference I found is not helpful it turns out. It seems doable by writing  $\exp(x)$ as a Taylor series (integrals of odd terms are 0, integrals of even terms are Gamma functions) but then the infinite sum has to be evaluated again which may be difficult. Maple can explicitly evaluate up to n=3 which suggests there is a general solution. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: @Peter: here's an alternative strategy but I haven't carried it out to completion yet. It's easy to integrate $\exp (\langle v, x \rangle)$ against a spherically symmetric Gaussian distribution in $\mathbb{R}^n$; this amounts to integrating $I(v, r)$ against $\exp(-tr^2)$ from $r = 0$ to $\infty$. Now this integral, as a function of $t$, is basically a somewhat deformed Laplace transform of $I(v, r)$, and in particular it ought to be possible to invert...

Comment: Ok - it would be nice to have a direct solution of course. In the mean time I figured out how to do $I(e_1,r)$ - you write $\exp(x)$ as a Taylor series as indicated above, you pull the sum out of the integral. You then get an infinite series which turns out to be a type of Bessel function. For odd n it can be written in the form a*sinh(..)+ b*cosh(..) , i.e. not as an infinite sum any more - that is explicit enough for me. I guess the case of even n is then also 'regular' enough for me to go on with, will need to study that.